# Insert Data to Firebase From Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, firebase

I am working on a Laravel project which is currently working with MySQL database. I have below code which is currently inserting data to MySQL database. What I need to do is to insert same data to Firebase instead of MySQL. Some solution I am getting is using javascript `<script>` tag but I can not use javascript in below page as it is giving error. Is there any way directly insert from below code. I am new and have no idea how to do that ?

```
$request  = new Request;
$request->user_id          =   $rider_id;
$request->group_id         =   null;
$request->pickup_latitude  =   $pickup_latitude;
$request->pickup_longitude =   $pickup_longitude;
$request->drop_latitude    =   $drop_latitude;
$request->drop_longitude   =   $drop_longitude;
$request->driver_id        =   $nearest_car->user_id;
$request->car_id           =   $car_id;
$request->pickup_location  =   $pickup_location;
$request->drop_location    =   $drop_location;
$request->payment_mode     =   $payment_method_store;
$request->status           =   'Pending';
$request->driver_mobile    =   $driver_details->mobile_number;//ad by me

$request->save(); //this method is saving to mysql
```

From here I need a method that will insert above value to Firebase

Comment: Have you checked this package https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/ ?

Comment: Thanks for the mention, Kevin . There‘s even a dedicated Laravel Package at https://github.com/kreait/laravel-firebase